# Deploy on Heroku dependency problems

Tags: node.js, reactjs, heroku, deployment, material-ui

Im trying to deploy on Heroku and i am stuck with some dependecy problems.
When I try to deploy with frontend node app I get the following error:

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  ^16.18.23
       engines.npm (package.json):   9.6.5
       
       Resolving node version ^16.18.23...
       Downloading and installing node 16.20.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 9.6.5 (replacing 8.19.4)...
       npm 9.6.5 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
       npm ERR! Found: @types/react@18.2.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
       npm ERR!   @types/react@"^18.2.0" from the root project
       npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"*" from @material-ui/types@5.1.0
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/types
       npm ERR!     @material-ui/types@"5.1.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
       npm ERR!     node_modules/@material-ui/styles
       npm ERR!       @material-ui/styles@"^4.11.5" from the root project
       npm ERR!   9 more (@mui/base, @mui/icons-material, @mui/material, ...)
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
       npm ERR! node_modules/@material-ui/styles
       npm ERR!   @material-ui/styles@"^4.11.5" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @types/react@17.0.58
       npm ERR! node_modules/@types/react
       npm ERR!   peerOptional @types/react@"^16.8.6 || ^17.0.0" from @material-ui/styles@4.11.5
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@material-ui/styles
       npm ERR!     @material-ui/styles@"^4.11.5" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! For a full report see:
       npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.CSqFU/_logs/2023-04-25T19_52_14_561Z-eresolve-report.txt
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /tmp/npmcache.CSqFU/_logs/2023-04-25T19_52_14_561Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

I understand that this is a dependecy problem in my package.json file and I think I understand that the problem (according to the error message) is that my @material-ui/types@5.1.0 wants the the version 16.8.6 or 17.0.0 of @types/react. So if I fix this problem and change it to 17.0.0 it will ask me to do the same for react and react-dom. But when I have fixed all of them. I get this error instead

```
-----> Building on the Heroku-22 stack
-----> Determining which buildpack to use for this app
-----> Node.js app detected
       
-----> Creating runtime environment
       
       NPM_CONFIG_LOGLEVEL=error
       NODE_VERBOSE=false
       NODE_ENV=production
       NODE_MODULES_CACHE=true
       
-----> Installing binaries
       engines.node (package.json):  ^16.18.23
       engines.npm (package.json):   9.6.5
       
       Resolving node version ^16.18.23...
       Downloading and installing node 16.20.0...
       Bootstrapping npm 9.6.5 (replacing 8.19.4)...
       npm 9.6.5 installed
       
-----> Installing dependencies
       Installing node modules
       npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
       npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! While resolving: @testing-library/react@13.4.0
       npm ERR! Found: react@17.0.2
       npm ERR! node_modules/react
       npm ERR!   react@"^17.0.0" from the root project
       npm ERR!   peer react@">=16.8.0" from @emotion/react@11.10.6
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@emotion/react
       npm ERR!     @emotion/react@"^11.10.6" from the root project
       npm ERR!     peer @emotion/react@"^11.0.0-rc.0" from @emotion/styled@11.10.6
       npm ERR!     node_modules/@emotion/styled
       npm ERR!       @emotion/styled@"^11.10.6" from the root project
       npm ERR!       4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers)
       npm ERR!     4 more (@mui/material, @mui/styled-engine, @mui/system, @mui/x-date-pickers)
       npm ERR!   17 more (@emotion/styled, ...)
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
       npm ERR! peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/@testing-library/react
       npm ERR!   @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: react@18.2.0
       npm ERR! node_modules/react
       npm ERR!   peer react@"^18.0.0" from @testing-library/react@13.4.0
       npm ERR!   node_modules/@testing-library/react
       npm ERR!     @testing-library/react@"^13.4.0" from the root project
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
       npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
       npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! 
       npm ERR! For a full report see:
       npm ERR! /tmp/npmcache.N6UAz/_logs/2023-04-25T20_19_13_720Z-eresolve-report.txt
       
       npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: /tmp/npmcache.N6UAz/_logs/2023-04-25T20_19_13_720Z-debug-0.log
-----> Build failed
       
       We're sorry this build is failing! You can troubleshoot common issues here:
       https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/troubleshooting-node-deploys
       
       If you're stuck, please submit a ticket so we can help:
       https://help.heroku.com/
       
       Love,
       Heroku
       
 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Node.js app.
 !     Push failed
```

So @testing-library wants react in version 18 and material ui wants it in 17. What do i do?

This is my package before any changes:

```
{
  "name": "mui",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@emotion/react": "^11.10.6",
    "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.6",
    "@material-ui/styles": "^4.11.5",
    "@mui/icons-material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/material": "^5.11.16",
    "@mui/x-date-pickers": "^6.1.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@types/jest": "^27.5.2",
    "@types/node": "^16.18.23",
    "@types/react": "^18.2.0",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.7",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.8.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "typescript": "^4.9.5",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "prettier": "2.8.7"
  },
  "engines": {
  "node": "^16.18.23",
  "npm": "9.6.5"
}
}
```

Extra info, with the above package it compiles/runs locally with no problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it worked in local but not Heroku, I knew it would work with the dependecy problem. By adding the Config Var NPM_CONFIG_LEGACY_PEER_DEPS with value true. It will run anyway